# Ubuntu Server Permission Problems

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, sudo, groups

Our sysadmin quit and I have been handed "the ropes."  Unfortunately, I don't know how to climb very well.

Here is my problem.

We have 4 servers that we use for our hosting of client's sites.  Anyway.

I'm trying to upload a file to this certain client's directory via sftp.  Getting permission denied.  I have sudo access to everything, and I discovered this folder and it's files were owned by an ex employee.

To change that I ran

```
sudo chown -R www-data public_html/
```

which made `www-data` owner of the directory and the sub files.

According to /etc/group I am in the group of www-data as well as our developers.

However, I am not able to upload/overwrite files.  When I go and change the owner -R to shutter (me) and all the files, I still cannot upload.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What error message are you getting ?

Comment: Error: /var/www/domainname.com/public_html/wp-content/themes/Chameleon/home.php: open for write: permission denied
Error: File transfer failed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, don't try uploading straight into a web folder. I would recommend uploading to your home folder, doing the necessary permission changes THEN copying(NOT moving) the files to that destination(will probably require sudo). That should do it.

Comment: I realize that this does it.  But here's another question.  What if I have hundreds of files to upload.  My devs don't have sudo access.  It would be a hinder to their productivity (and mine) to have them ask me to sudo cp files over.

Comment: It may 'hinder' their productivity but there are certain ways of doing things in a production environment. Sftping into a production web folder can have some nasty consequences if you have a brain fart. As such, best practice dictates you dump the files into a neutral location THEN copy them over. If best practices are not much of a concern then I'm kind of at a loss on how to help as I don't work that way :P